# Get data from child product

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a module that observes the status and writes a value into the database.
When the product is simple, it works. But when it is configurable, it writes the value of the Pattern Product and not of the Child.

```
if (($status !== $previousStatus) && ($status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)) {
  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
  foreach($items as $item){
    $cd = $item->getProduct()->getData('cd');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bd`.`table` (`id`, `cd`) VALUES (NULL, '$cd')");
  }
  return true;
}
```

How to identify if it is a configurable product, and get data from the child product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Magento already has a connection initialised, you don't need to spin up another one directly.
2. You shouldn't have to specify the database you're connecting to directly.
3. A configurable product can contain a simple product, to access this you'll need to get the childItem.
4. The preferred approach for this kind of thing would be to store the products data against the order item, so that if a product is deleted etc in the future you have a full history because order items are decoupled from their products data at time of placing. Read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62111/what-is-the-effect-of-deleting-a-product-with-associated-orders/62142#62142
5. Just a FYI but `getAllVisibleItems` returns configurables, if you wanted to see configurables and their simples all in one collection you could use getAllItems instead

   ```
   if (($status !== $previousStatus) && ($status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)) {
       /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
       $order = $observer->getData('order');
       $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

       /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
       foreach($items as $item){
           $cd = $item->getProduct()->getData('cd');

           //If configurable get the first child item and the cd value from it
           if ($item->getProductType() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
               $childrenItems = $item->getChildrenItems();
               $childItem = reset($childrenItems);
               if ($childItem instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item) {
                   $cd = $childItem->getProduct()->getData('cd');
               }
           }

           /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource $resource */
           $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
           $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

           $query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`cd`) VALUES ('{$cd}')";
           $writeConnection->query($query);
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Worked perfectly :) A question, when the status is PENDING, does not take the value of $cd. How to fix it?

Comment: Your initial condition at the top filters out the different order states. Try changing the condition there. `&& (in_array($status, array(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT))`

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your SQL connection - you should revise that - take a look here:http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

To get the chosen child product of a configurable product, do this;

```
foreach($items as $item){    

     // Establish product type and if configurable, load the chosen product
     if ($item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        $simple = reset($item->getChildren());
        $_product = $simple->getProduct();
     } else {
       $_product = $item->getProduct();
     }

  $cd = $_product->getData('cd');
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bd`.`table` (`id`, `cd`) VALUES (NULL, '$cd')");

}
```

Comment: Loading within a for loop, very bad for performance.  Any data required should be loaded by `item->getProduct()` which is lazy loaded and object cached against the item. See `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getProduct`

Comment: agree that this is usually a bad idea, this is a snippet we used where the data we wanted was not within the $item->getProduct() object which necessitated a full load. Worth noting this is being called on an order, so chances of there being hundreds of items in there is pretty slim.

Comment: revised nevertheless :)